# Unable to interpret p statistics for periodicity testing of signals

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, signal-processing

The meaning of P value is probability which should be number between 0 (the event never occurs) and 1 (the event occurs always). [significance testing for periodicity using Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/significance-testing-for-periodic-component.html) gives a documentation on how to apply Fisher's statistics to a time series signal for periodicity testing. Some concepts are unclear to me and I shall be grateful for an intuitive answer:

Q1: In my example, I want to prove if the signal is periodic or not. So something that I want to prove to be true becomes the null hypothesis statement? Thus, would

```
 H0: the signal is periodic and H1: not periodic?
```

Q2: For my signal I got the value of `pval = 2.3e-6`, `fmax (the maximum frequency) =  0.0078`  and `fisher_g = 0.1136`. How do I interpret this result? Is my signal periodic or not?

Q3:   If the calculated `pval` is less than the threshold which usually is taken as `0.05` then do we reject the null hypothesis? In the documentation it is the opposite and the threshold is `0.000001` which I do not know how it has come. I am confused! Please correct me where wrong.

Comment: There are several questions here.  The duplicate addresses the more fundamental ones.  After you have had a chance to read it, you might want to edit and focus this post on anything that hasn't been cleared up.

Comment: My question is completely different from the one linked as duplicate. My question is different in two aspects-(1) I am trying to understand how to design a hypothesis and which statement goes under what type of hypothesis. (2) I got a pvalue of say 1 for one experiment using one type of time series and for another experiment using another time series I got a different pvalue of say 2.3e-6. Under the hypothesis, would the first experiemtn be considered as a nonlinear time series and the second one as periodic?

Comment: You're right.  I apologize!  Somehow I linked to the wrong thread; I have updated that. The information given in the duplicate ought to make the answers to your questions obvious.